# Linear momentum of an EM wave

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, optics

In my optics textbook, the derivation of the expression for the linear momentum of a plane wave shocks me as rather sloppy, but I don't know if I should be so shocked. It goes as follows:

Let a plane EM wave travel (in the vacuum) in the direction of the unit vector $\vec{s}$. Then, since the wave has an energy $E$ associated to it, we can define its (rest?) mass to be:

$$m = \frac{E}{c^2}$$

Therefore, we can now define its linear momentum as:

$$\vec{p} = m\vec{v} = \frac{E}{c^2}\vec{c} = \frac{E}{c}\vec{s}$$

The textbook then goes on to define the linear momentum density ($\vec{P}$) simply dividing both terms of the equation by the volume $V$ and naming $W=\frac{E}{V}$ as the energy density of the wave, sowe can now write:

$$\vec{P} = \frac{W}{c}\vec{s} = \frac{\vec{S}}{c^2}$$

where $\vec{S}$ is the wave's Poynting vector. Now, a couple of questions regarding this procedure:

1. Does it make sense to define a rest mass for an EM wave if it's always going to be moving?
2. Does it make sense to apply the classical definition of linear momentum to an EM wave, which is *the most* relativistic thing you can get? I can't even fathom how we could approach this problem otherwise, since the Lorentz factor would diverge for $v=c$.

As always, thank you for your answers

Comment: are you working in a classical electromagnetism or relativity framework?

Comment: @basics the whole module covers electromagnetic optics, which I assume is entirely classical since it's a second year module

Comment: I'm saving the question for tomorrow, since it's quite late here.

Answer (score 1):

For an entity that travels at the speed of light, the rest mass is defined to be zero. However the quantity $m$ in the above derivation is not the rest mass, but the "relativistic mass" which can be defined as $E/c^2$ (and, for massive particles, also equals $\gamma m_0$, where I'm using the symbol $m_0$ to represent the rest mass). When mass is replaced by "relativistic mass", the Newtonian formula $\mathbf{p} = m\mathbf{v}$ actually holds even for relativistic particles.

Because modern physics education frowns on the concept of relativistic mass, we can eliminate it altogether in the following alternative derivation. Assume that the photon's rest mass is an infinitesimal quantity $m_0$ rather than being exactly zero. Since $E = \gamma m_0 c^2$ and $\mathbf{p} = \gamma m_0 \mathbf{v}$, we can eliminate $\gamma$ and $m_0$ to obtain $\mathbf{p} = \frac{E}{c^2}\mathbf{v}$, which in the case of light reduces to $\mathbf{p} = \frac{E}{c} \hat{\bf k}$.

And even if the photon's mass is exactly zero, we assume that the final result above is still valid because we don't expect any discontinuous jumps in observable properties when a parameter goes from an infinitesimal value to exactly zero. (Is that actually true? Well, the answer is that there's no way to know for sure, because we can't prove experimentally that the mass of the photon is exactly zero anyway. We can only prove that it's below detection limits.)